# How to show or hide Outlook Infobar using VSTO add-in for outlook desktop (office 365)

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

Infobar of Outlook shows up when not forwarding a mail by canceling it using an add-in.

Tried hiding it using WIN32 api but couldn't do it because of no proper info on how to do it.

The API methods used are :

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);

[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool EnableWindow(IntPtr hwnd, bool enabled);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
```

Have to find a way to hide and show infobar either with win32 api or any other way.